# ExpressJS Login Validation Error: comparePassword is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, backend

In the folder **backend/controllers** I have an ***authController*** class which handles a POST request with an email and password and then looks for a user in the database with a matching email, then when it finds the user, it tries to verify the password invoking a method called **comparePassword** which is defined in the ***user*** class located in **backend/models**.

The authController class:

```js
const User = require('../models/user');
const ErrorHandler = require('../utils/errorHandler');
const catchAsynErrors = require('../middlewares/catchAsyncErrors');
const sendToken = require('../utils/jwtToken');


// register user => /api/v1/register
exports.registerUser = catchAsynErrors(async (req, res, next)=> {
const { name, email, password} = req.body;

const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email, 
    password,
    avatar: {
        public_id: '',
        url: ''
    }
})

sendToken(user, 200, res)
})



// login user => /a[i/v1/login
exports.loginUser = catchAsynErrors(async(req, res, next)=> {
    const { email, password} = req.body;

    // checks if email  and password is entered by the user
    if(!email || !password){
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Please enter email & password', 400))
    }

    //finding user in database
    const user = await User.find( { email } ).select('+password')

    if(!user){
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Invalid Email or Password', 401))
    }
    
    // Attempting to print the user object's functions
    console.log(user.comparePassword); // undefined
    console.log(user.find); // [Function: find]
    
    //checks if password is correct or not 
    const isPasswordMatched = await user.comparePassword(password);
    
    if(!isPasswordMatched){
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Invalid Email or Password', 401))
    }
    sendToken(user, 200, res)   
});
```

The user class:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const userSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter your name'],
    maxLenght: [30, 'Your name cannot exceed 30 characters']
},
email:{
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter your email'],
    unique: true, 
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email address']
}, 
password:{
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter your password'],
    minlenght: [6, 'Your password must have at least 6 characters'],
    select: false
},
avatar:{
    public_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    url:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

},
role:{
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
},
createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpire: Date
})

//encrypting password before saving user
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next){
    if(!this.isModified('password')){
        next()
    }
    this.password = await  bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10)
})

// compare user password
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
    return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password)
}


// return jwt token 
userSchema.methods.getJwtToken = function (){
    return jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_TIME
    });
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And this is the result I get when I try to make a POST request with [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLRFW.png)
along with what the [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz5Ro.png) (in this case, via the VS Code Terminal) shows upon trying to console.log the function comparePassword alongside the function find, both of which belong on the same class.

Postman:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 500
    },
    "errMessage": "user.comparePassword is not a function",
    "stack": "TypeError: user.comparePassword is not a function\n    at D:\\pruebas de programación\\Proyectazo\\backend\\controllers\\authController.js:47:42\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)"
}
```

Console:

```
PS D:\pruebas de programación\Proyectazo> npm run dev
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> proyectazo@1.0.0 dev
> SET NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT& nodemon backend/server

[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json  
[nodemon] starting `node backend/server.js` 
Server started on PORT: 4000 in DEVELOPMENT mode. 
MongoDB Database connected with HOST: localhost
undefined
[Function: find]
```

I've made it this far following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zXBZS6E-jM&list=PLkVd4_IMjZgkwcXwnpy7tenGNBbRdiRO8&index=27 and it appears to work perfectly in the video. I looked up other solutions, some of them even within StackOverflow, and they all look like variants or refactors of the same implementation that I have. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working because in loginUser function

```
//finding user in database
    const user = await User.find( { email } ).select('+password')
```

`user` is an array.
Instead use Use.findOne() method

```
// This will return single user object
        const user = await User.findOne( { email } ).select('+password')
```

Comment: It works!!! Thank you for your help. I am new in stackoverflow sorry i can not rate.

Comment: No problem at all, glad it worked!